# paypal IPN works but stuck at paypal's thank you page!

Tags: php, paypal

my paypal ipn php works correctl. i tested it out with sandbox account, and the payment works, my database is updated properly etc.

however, I expected the page to redirect back to my shopping site. instead it just sits at paypal's Thank You For your Payment page.

how can i make it redirect back to my shopping site ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032167/paypal-ipn-trouble-thank-you-for-your-payment-and-doesnt-redirect-back-to-my-si

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the payment form, you have to set a return field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://mywebsite.com/success.php" />
```

This will give the user a button that says: Go back to merchant's page. Additionally, if you want them to automatically be redirected back to your shopping site, without clicking anything, there's a profile option, in the PayPal website, called Auto Return.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes. that was the problem. i have to set the auto return on profile.